# Microsoft SQL Server - Cursor errors

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a script that uses the AP database to declare and use a cursor for the following select statement. I also have to use a WHILE loop to fetch each row in the result set, and omit the INTO clause to fetch directly to the Results tab.

```
SELECT VendorName, AVG (Invoice Total) AS InvoiceAvg 
FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices 
 ON Vendors. VendorID = Invoices. VendorID
GROUP BY VendorName;
```

When I ran the script that I had created below, I kept on getting numerous errors in regards to incorrect syntax.

```
USE AP;
GO

DECLARE
    CURSOR cursor1 is
        SELECT VendorName, AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceAvg
        FROM Vendors JOIN Invoices
        ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
        GROUP BY VendorName;
BEGIN
    WHILE rs IN cursor1
        LOOP
            Dbms_output.put_line('Name=' || rs.LastName || ',Average=' || rs.AVG);
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Here are the errors that I came across.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURSOR'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'cursor1'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'LOOP'.
```

How can I get the code to run correctly without getting any errors?

Comment: SQL Server does not use `Dbms_output`, Oracle does. Your error looks like SQL though. Please confirm this is not Oracle

Comment: ...and why not just run the query directly? why output it line by line? Anyway I suggest you google `t-sql cursor examples`

Comment: are you trying to run Oracle PL/SQL code on SQL Server?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Loop based methods aren't performant in RDBMS, you should be using a set-based operation. Explain the real goal you have here.

Comment: Although we could correct your script to use T-SQL syntax and a `PRINT` statement instead of the hybrid of Oracle PL/SQL and T-SQL, I agree with @Larnu it would be better if  to explain your use actual case. Is this just for learning T-SQL? With Microsoft SQL Server, one normally returns data as a streaming result set directly instead of as text output messages and avoids server-side cursors.